# Validating uitextfield while editing

Tags: ios, regex, xcode, validation, uitextfield

I want to validate the text from my text field while editing.I have this regex `@"^(01)?[- .]?(\\([2-9]\\d{2}\\)|[2-9]\\d{2})[- .]?\\d{3}[- .]?\\d{4}$"` and I use the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method and if a wrong symbol is entered I want to return "NO", so the symbol wont be printed. I tried with `NSPredicate`, but couldn't do it.

Comment: Post the code you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this extension to your class file

```
extension String
{
    var isValid: Bool {
        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "your regularexpression here", options: .CaseInsensitive)
            return regex.firstMatchInString(self, options: NSMatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count)) != nil
        } catch {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Use this in your `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` textfield function

```
if (label.text!.isValid)
{
//do your action here
}
```